# Writing a merge statement in SQL

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-merge

The process is one where I would get 28 fixed width files and combine it into one table. In the past, this was done via FoxPro. As I have learned today, there were duplicates for which FoxPro did not reject or have any issues with. I have discovered that I need to write a merge statement in order to import the 28 and not get tripped up by duplicate primary key errors when I try to import each one separately using the Import Wizard.

I use Management Studio with a SQL Server Express front end and therefore can't create SSIS packages.

I am going to break this up into two questions so as to not make this too convoluted. First, I have since converted the fixed width files into tab-delimited text files by using Excel.

First question: Can one construct a merge statement that brings the files (tab-delimited) into SQL Server from the C drive? I could import each using the import wizard but that is cumbersome. I know how to write a merge statement but it demands that the data already exist in SQL Server. Below is an example. The question is how would I bring it in from outside.

```
 Merge Industry as TARGET
 Using Table1 as SOURCE
 On (TARGET.Primary keys 1-9 = SOURCE.Primary keys 1-9)
```

Comment: In SMSS Object Explorer -> right click your database select Task>Import Data and then in the new window pick `Flat File Source` that would let import your file to a table and do the marge later

Comment: @smog,  I was hoping to avoid that due to the presence of duplicates. Repeating this process 28 times may be what I have to do, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't import data during or as part of a `MERGE` statement. The `MERGE` operation is purely for the 'upsert' situation; constructing logic on combining two result sets with criteria for matches and mismatches.

To get data into SQL Server you can either work via the UI (which is pretty boring and error prone when you have 28 files), or you can use some of the built in commands such as [`BULK INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql).

Perhaps you could `BULK INSERT` the files one by one, and merge after each import.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to continue using Foxpro but eliminate the duplicate records the first piece of advice would be to quit using the **Import Wizard**.

Wizards may be convenient to use, but they come with their own set of 'baggage' which can be problematic.

Aside from saying that they are in fixed field length format, you don't indicate which format(s) the 28 import files are in (CSV, SDF, TXT, ect.).  Regardless you can farily easily write Foxpro code to handle all of the importing without the use of a 'Wizard'.

Then once all of the records have been imported you can readily eliminate the duplicates with something like the following:

```
SELECT ImportDBF   && Assuming it is used EXCLUSIVELY
DELETE ALL
INDEX ON <primary key> UNIQUE TAG Uniq  && Create an Index on only UNIQUE instances of your Primary key field
RECALL ALL  && Recall only those UNIQUE records
DELETE TAG Uniq  && Eliminate the temporary Index 
PACK  && PACK out the duplicate records
```

Now your Foxpro data table should be ready to go.

Good Luck